# Why won't my array print the rest of the columns?

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption

I'm very curious about encryption so I went out and gave myself a little task, to encrypt a message (below in my `.txt` file).  I'm not getting the output I want, I'm only getting the first column.  Why's it only printing the first column?

Here's my `java` file:

```
import java.io.*;

public class EncryptDecrypt {

    public static void encrypt() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("cryptographyTextFile.txt"));
        String line = in.readLine();

        char[][] table = new char[5][5];

        // fill array
        for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < table.length; j++) {
                table[i][j] = line.charAt(j);   
            }
        }

        // print array
        for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < table.length; j++) {
                System.out.println(table[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        encrypt();
    }
}
```

My `.txt` file contains:

```
E5NOWISTHEWINTEROFOURDISCONTENT*
```

My `output` is:

```
E
5
N
O
W
```

I want my `output` to be:

```
E I T W O O D
5 S H I F U I
N   E N   R S
O     T     C
W     E     O
      R     N
            T  
            E 
            N  
            T
```

Comment: You can just select anything on the fly. You have to write an algorithm to encrypt and decry-pt then implement in your logic to encrypt or decrypt text. Some kind of delimiter to specify that this text will go in first column and next text in next column.  
If you want to learn more about this you can refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html

Comment: @Leozeo I don't need anything too fancy for now.  Something simple that'll read this column by column and print it out like I mentioned in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are just iterating along the rows.
In the `for` loop, `table.length` moves along the rows (that is vertically), whereas `table[0].length` will iterate along the columns, that is on a single row (horizontally)

So you may want to change your loop to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
       //your code here   
    }
}
```

Also, you need to have separate counter for your string. Your value of `j` is limited to the size of your array column length, namely from `0` to `4`.
For idea, try this:

```
String line = in.readLine();
int cnt = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
    while(cnt<line.length()){
      table[i][j] = line.charAt(cnt);
      cnt++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm I see what you're saying.  I tried what you said but all I'm getting is the output that I've posted in my original post only in repeated fashion going vertically.

Comment: I just thought you needed help with the loop. I edited with few more pointers. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This part has an issue

```
for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < table.length; j++) {
                table[i][j] = line.charAt(j);   
            }
        }
```

You are only filling characters from j=0 to j=5 as your char array is of size 5 (you are retrieving first 5 characters of the line). I am unsure of what are you trying to achieve as a character array with 5X5 is not the answer.

If your txt file has line delimiters, you can make use of them and read each word into a string and have an array of strings.

I am leaving the explanation here as I couldn't make much out the question